# MySql running slow when connecting with php. working fast when connecting with workbench

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange issue with our mysql server. When connecting with a php script using mysqli it's taking around 45 seconds to get a result, my query `SELECT userId FROM user WHERE userId = '8155'`. When connecting from mysql workbench its less than 0.5 second. There is no issue with my php script its just a simple connect and query. I checked phpmyadmin on the server its working fast like normal too. My best guess is its some kinda network issue.

Thanks in advance

More info: after doing some more searching i found maybe adding 
`--skip-name-resolve` may help.

i found that the slowness is in connecting only. query and responses are quick.

Comment: Try without quote: SELECT userId FROM user WHERE userId = 8155  , and add LIMIT 1. Perhaps this help ;)

Comment: na that didnt work :-)

Comment: The webserver where your php files reside is not the same machine that runs the database? From where are you connecting with phpmyadmin / Workbench? Show some of your code.

Comment: yes it was a different server. The issue is solved now. It was caused by some configurations with the LXC, server team fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the server not mysql or php. Server admins fixed it. so if this happen to anyone just call the server support guys.

Comment: Could you explain what the server guys told you it was?

Comment: @ChrisMuench http://www.vionblog.com/skip-name-resolve-to-speed-up-mysql-and-avoid-problems/